# Individual property update vs object re assigning in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an object like this.

```
steps:any = [
    {
        id: 1, name: "A", next: [{ id: 2, name: "B" }, { id: 3, name: "C" }]
    },
    {
        id: 2, name: "B", next: [{ id: 1, name: "B" }]
    },
    {
        id: 3, name: "C", next: [{ id: 1, name: "B" }]
    },
    {
        id: 4, name: "D", next: [{ id: 1, name: "B" }]
    }
]
```

and on HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let step of steps">
    {{step.name}}
    <div *ngFor="let nextStep of step.next">
        <span (click)="change(step,nextStep)">{{nextStep.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and ts

```
change(step, nextStep) {
    let __step = this.steps.find((_step) => {
        return _step.id === step.id;
    });

   let __nextStep = __step.next.find((_nextStep) => {
     return _nextStep.id === nextStep.id;
   });
   __nextStep = {name:"XYZ",id:"10",next:[]}
}
```

According to this the clicked object must change its value? What this is not working, the `name` remains the same, but if I do

```
__nextStep.name ="XYZ";
```

it works, but if assign the object not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__nextStep` is just a local variable that initially holds a reference to an element of `steps`. When you reassign it with:

```
__nextStep = {name:"XYZ",id:"10",next:[]};
```

you're not doing anything to the original object. Assigning to a variable has no effect on the object that the variable previously referred to.

You can use `Object.assign()` to replace the properties of an existing object:

```
Object.assign(__nextStep, {name:"XYZ",id:"10",next:[]});
```

Comment: Thanks!! it worked and will accept the answer in 3 minutes as you can't accept before 5 min, StackOverflow thinks humans are slower than machines!! :)

Comment: The reason for the delay is to allow time for other people to post better answers, so you don't just accept the first answer you get.

Comment: oh that is nice!! and valid reasoning

Answer (score 1):

That's because your object is a new memory reference.

When you write

```
__nextStep = {name:"XYZ",id:"10",next:[]}
```

Your create a new memory reference, which has nothing to do with the previous value, and Angular loops are looking for changes inside memory references you provide at start.

This means that since your new memory reference is out of the array, Angular doesn't change it.

If you want to be able to assign new memory references and still check for changes, you'll have to write a custom trackby function that tracks by name.

```html
<div *ngFor="let step of steps; trackBy: customTB">
```

```js
customTB(index, item) {
  return `${index}-${item.name}$`;
}
```

You can also try with

```
<div *ngFor="let step of steps; trackBy: step.name">
```

But i've never tested it myself.

Answer (score -1):

You are updating only the local value to update the value you need to find the index from the array like this

```
change(step, nextStep) {
    let __stepIndex = this.steps.findIndex((_step) => {
    _step.id === step.id;
    });
    let __nextStepIndex =this.steps[__stepIndex].next.findIndex((_nextStep) => {
  _nextStep.id === nextStep.id;
});
__nextStep = {name:"XYZ",id:"10",next:[]};
this.steps[__stepIndex].next[__nextStepIndex]=__nextStep;
}
```